# How to write regular expression to check starts with in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the index by using the following mapping:

```
PUT test9
{
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "text"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I have added the following documents into it:

```
PUT test9/type1/1/_create
{
  "name":"suraj"
}

PUT test9/type1/2/_create
{
  "name":"nitesh"
}

PUT test9/type1/3/_create
{
  "name":"suresh"
}
```

Now I want to check the documents whose name starts with "**sur**" using the regular expression. So I have used the following query:

```
GET test9/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp":{
      "name":"^sur"
    }
  }
}
```

The above query not giving any kind of result. Please let me know what is wrong here? How to write the regular expression in elastic search?
Can we use mongo regular expression directly into elastic search ?

Comment: Everything is perfect just change "^sur" to "sur.*". Second thing i would suggest dont use wildcard or regex query. Those are slow. To achieve your use case, You can use ngram or edge_ngram tokenizer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

3 ways you can achieve this in elasticsearch:

```
GET test9/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": "sur"
    }
  }
}


GET test9/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard":{
      "name":"sur*"
    }
  }
}

GET test9/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp":{
      "name":"sur.*"
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**

prefix, regexp and wildcard work only on not_analyzed parts of fields. So operator ^ of standard regular expressions is not allowed. See the links for allowed regex characters.

**RESOURCES:**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: How we can use "^sur" with query_string query instead of regular expression query?